# How do I mount a TV with clock type mount?

Tags: mounting, television, clock

[image]

The distance is 20 inches between 2 holes.

Comment: How heavy is the TV, and what kind of wall are you trying to mount it on?

Comment: TV should be 5-6 kgs. Wall is of cement brick but not very hard or solid. In fact if we do not put proper plug, the screw will cut through the wall.

Comment: For future reference, that "clock type mount" is called a keyhole slot. They're quite common on all sorts of things designed to be mounted on walls and usually used for lighter items like routers, clocks and pictures.

Answer (score 5):

1. The hard way: stick two screws in the wall at the proper spacing, with heads that fit in the holes, sticking out of the wall far enough that they can go into the holes and slide up into the slots. Explore the bounds of your profanity vocabulary while trying to get the holes to line up with the screws where you can't see behind the TV.
2. The easy way: put the screws into a board with a bevel cut on the edge, with the bevel cut facing downwards, and the screws on the side with the obtuse angle. Mount a matching bevel cut board to the wall with the acute angle outwards, facing up. Put the board on the TV, slide it into place in the slots, then pick the TV up and slide onto the board on the wall. That's a **French cleat.**

Comment: French cleat is a great idea.  As far as option one, consider using a piece of painters tape, stick it to the back of the TV, mark the hole locations and then transfer the tape to the wall for final layout.

Comment: Thank you for the response.1. Wont the screws hurt the plastic slot? 2. How do I attach the TV to the board?

Comment: The slots are intended to hold the heads (not the pointy end) of screws screwed into something (the wall, a board.) Which is how the TV is held to the board when the screws are in the board. The tape suggestion works to put the screws in the right place in the wall, but does nothing for the frustrating process of getting the screws into the holes while holding the TV up to the wall. Using the French cleat means you can do that fiddly bit wile being able to see, and then landing it on the mating cleat is much easier.

Comment: Happiness is a set of _dowel centers_. ([Lee Valley Tools](https://www.leevalley.com/en-us/shop/tools/hand-tools/marking-and-measuring/marking-tools/44995-dowel-and-tenon-centers) for example.) They fit in the large ends of the keyholes and you align the item where desired and press it against the wall to mark the positions. The only detail is accounting for the drop when the screwheads slide in the keyholes, assuming that the height needs to be precise.

Comment: Thank you very much @Ecnerwal